# Running a JAX-WS service with SSL security on WebLogic

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, weblogic

I am migrating a application that curently runs on a Tomcat Sever to WebLogic cluster and I have found a very specific problem.

This application has a WebService that can, if so is the client will, run with SSL. We accomplish that on Tomcat by configuring the proper valve and redirecting all **HTTP** requests to **HTTPS**. This way, our **WSDL** will have the correct port address to be accessed through HTTPS as follows:

```
<port name="WebServidorWSPort" binding="tns:WebServidorWSPortBinding">
    <soap:address location="https://tomcat:8443/WebServidor/WebServidorWS"/>
</port>
```

I have done a similar configuration on our WebLogic cluster, and I am able to access the **WSLD** through HTTPS, but the port declaration still is nor right as in the snipped **WSLD** below:

```
 <port name="WebServidorWSPort" binding="tns:WebServidorWSPortBinding">
     <soap:address location="http://weblogic:8000/WebServidor/WebServidorWS"/>
 </port>
```

It is kind of using the HTTP front-end configuration, even with the HTTPS frontend configured. And when accessing this URL I get a HTTP 302 to the HTTPS address, rising an error on the client application.

How should I configure the server or the application to correct generate the port with the HTTPS address?

Comment: To start debugging go to your admin console `Server -> Protocols -> HTTP` tab in put in the information int the `Frontend` section. That may solve the problem. You can define both the http and https ports

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp, I've already configured the cluster and server frontend host and port for both protocols (HTTP and HTTPS). But I still have the same problem: on WSLD, the port configuration point to the HTTP address, not HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this configuration, I had to upgrade my web.xml to Servlet 3.0 specification.

This way, on the administration console, by selecting the application I can know access a option to configure the deployed Web Services, and on Configuration > WS-Policy I can add configure TLS security.

Here is a link to use as reference:

[Oracle WebLogic documentation - How to configure WS-Policy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24401/taskhelp/webservices/ConfigureWSPolicyFile.html)